# How to redirect user after sign in with Devise, and how to add method to Devise registration controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Using Rails 3.2.8, Devise 2.1.2, & Simpleform 2.0.2

I'm trying to redirect user upon successful sign in & sign out using devise.

So do I need to modify the controller if so how (specifics)? 
Or do I need to implement [the redirect helper](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in-or-sign-out), if so where do I put the helper?

Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this by adding following to your application_controller

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  some_path
end

def after_sign_out_path_for(resource)
  root_url
end
```

I think resource is a User class, so you can check for type and redirect them to appropriate path.

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfect! I couldn't find that anywhere.

Comment: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in-out here is doc for it.